# Certificate error on meta.physics.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, ssl

Visiting https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ gives me a certificate error in Chrome. Here is the certificate that I receive when visiting that page:

[image]

Comment: HTTPS is not fully supported yet. One of the problems is the format of meta urls.